# 'textContent' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, ie-developer-tools

i have a problem with this code
this code run great on all browsers exept IE,my IE is 8.0
any solution?
i won't using jquery
sincerely
Note: i changed Node.TEXT_NODE to 3 but other error occured:'textContent' is null or not an object

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script>

 function replaceText(oldText, newText, node){ 
   node = node || document.body; 

   var childs = node.childNodes, i = 0;

   while(node = childs[i]){ 
     if (node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE){ 
  node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(oldText, newText); 
} else { 
  replaceText(oldText, newText, node); 
} 
     i++; 
   } 
 }

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 old
 <h1 id="myHeader" onclick="replaceText('old','new')">old Click me! whatever</h1>

 </body>
 </html>
```

i found it

```
   while(i < childs.length){
   if (rgx.test(document.body.innerHTML)){
   childs[i][textPropName] =childs[i][textPropName].replace(rgx,'new');
   }
   else
   {
   replaceText(oldText, newText,document.body.childNodes[i])
   }
        i++; 
      } 
    }
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - I've corrected that.

Comment: i'm sory i use space for java script then forget to correct it after edit

Answer (score 3):

`Node.TEXT_NODE` & `textContent` are not available in IE8.

---

Use `3` instead of `Node.TEXT_NODE`, and use `innerText` if `textContent` is not available:

```
var textPropName = node.textContent === undefined ? 'innerText' : 'textContent';

if (node.nodeType == 3) {
    node[textPropName] = node[textPropName].replace(oldText, newText); 
} else { 
    replaceText(oldText, newText, node); 
}
```

You should probably cache that `textPropName` outside your function, so that you don't recheck it every single time the function is called (use `document.body` for the test).

Comment: thanks Joseph but i changed it to 3 ago but give me this error again 'textContent' is null or not an object

Comment: @MD66 - I forgot to mention that IE8 does not support `textContent`; It uses `innerText` instead. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Silber thanks but on this line give undefined error node[textPropName] = node[textPropName].replace(oldText, newText);

Answer (score 2):

instead of textContent, use nodeValue

```
node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(oldText, newText);
```